# Business Objects - Inputs controls suddenly applying to other report sheets

Tags: filtering, business-objects

Sometimes when I use input controls whose dependency relates to either report elements as tables or to complete reports (report sheets), the following behaviour takes place: Some time after creating them, all of a sudden, they are applied to other reports. And, worse, it is not or almost not possible to to "get rid of them" there; suppressing their effect there.
Sometimes, it is possible to remove them at the places they suddenly appear by adding a second input control, what triggers an AND branch in the "Document Structure and Filters" overview, and to remove it there by rightclicking.
Does anybody know:

- how this behaviour can be avoided? or
- in case it appears, how it can be easily undone?

Comment: What version of BusinessObjects are you on? Can you provide some screenshots for a little more context? If you can provide an example with the eFashion universe exhibiting the issue then I can build the same and work with it on my system that would be great.

Comment: Version: SAP BusinessObjects BI Platform 4.2 Support Pack 8 Patch 8
Situation (in words, since I cannot paste pictures here):

initial on "Document structure and filters":
<report name>
  <one applied filter (input control)>
      <Variable1>
      ...

after having applied input control on other report sheet (with dependency on single object on that sheet):
<report name>
  <one applied filter (input control)>
  <input control applied on other sheet, desplayed here (and unfortunately taking effect on this sheet)>
      <Variable1>
      ...

how can I access the "eFashion"?

Comment: You cannot post pictures in a comment, but if you edit your question you can added pictures there.  The eFashion universe is usually part of all BusinessObjects installs. Perhaps your admins removed it.